# How to abort a fish script from a lower-level function?

Tags: shell, return, abort, fish

Given a fish script `foo.fish` that only prints "foo", help, or an error

```
function foo
  __parse_args $argv[1]
  echo foo
end

function __parse_args --argument option
  if test -z $option
    return  # No option to parse, return early
  end

  switch $option
    case -h --help
      echo "Shows this help and exits"
      return 0  # How can we exit 0 instead of return?
    case -\*
      echo "Error: '$option' not a valid option"
      return 1  # How can we exit 1 instead of return?
  end
end
```

Actual behaviour:

```
↪ foo -h
Shows this help and exits
foo
```

Expected behaviour:

```
↪ foo -h
Shows this help and exits
```

The `return` manual says it stops the current inner function and sets the exit status of the function.

How can we exit the script early when inside nested function calls, with the appropriate exit code?

Note we cannot use `exit` because it will exit the shell instead of just the script.

Comment: What do you mean "exit the shell instead of just the script"? Unless you are sourcing the script with `source` or `.`, the script is run in its own shell.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you run the script via `source` or `.`,it is run in its own new shell process. The `exit` command will terminate that process and return to the parent shell that invoked the script; the parameter to `exit` will be the value of `$status` inside that parent process immediately after the exit.

If you are actually defining the `foo` function in your interactive shell (via `source` or `.` or typing/pasting at your shell prompt or by defining it in your .fishrc or a startup file in ~/.config or whatever) then there is no way for `__parse_args` to return from `foo`. `foo` will have to check the return value of `__parse_args` (that is, check `$status` after calling `__parse_args`) explicitly and then return immediately if appropriate. That also means that it's up to `__parse_args` to return a different value when processing `--help` than when otherwise successful.

However, unless the actual operation of `foo` involves some modification to your shell environment, I would recommend making it an executable script file instead of a function, for example by putting this into a file named `foo` somewhere in your command search `$PATH`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env fish
function foo
  __parse_args $argv[1]
  echo foo
end

function __parse_args --argument option
  if test -z $option
    return  # No option to parse, return early
  end

  switch $option
    case -h --help
      echo "Shows this help and exits"
      exit 0  # How can we exit 0 instead of return?
    case -\*
      echo "Error: '$option' not a valid option"
      exit 1  # How can we exit 1 instead of return?
  end
end

foo $argv
```

That has the desired result:

```
> foo
foo
> foo -x
Error: '-x' not a valid option
[1]> foo -h
Shows this help and exits
>
```

Comment: In the sample script, change `return 0` to `exit 0` for example, then copy paste the functions and execute `foo -h`. The shell you ran it in will close. According to the `exit` manual, it will exit the (fish) shell. Only if exit is called while sourcing a file will the rest of the file be skipped instead of exiting the shell itself.

Comment: Yes, but copying and pasting at the prompt is the same as `source` or `.` - you're defining the functions in your interactive shell, and then just running the function. 

There is no way to exit from multiple levels of function call in `fish`. I recommend just making it a script.

Comment: Creating a script at `~/.config/fish/functions/foo.fish` still exits the shell.

Comment: Note the short-circuit suggestion only handles the failure case (return 1 from error), not the graceful case (return 0 from help).

Comment: True. The caller would need another switch/case on `$status` to do the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

Coming into this very late, but the reason that the script that Mark provided was still exiting the shell for Dennis appears to be that it was placed in ~/.config/fish/functions/foo.fish, which is the function path, not the executable path.  This means that the foo function was being autoloaded and executed instead of the foo script itself.  In this case, the "exit" was aborting the function (and thus the shell), not the script's process.

Placing the script in the PATH, not the function path, should allow it to work.

Alternatively, if you really do want to run it as an auto-loaded function, the following is a bit convoluted, but works as a script/function in ~/.config/fish/functions.  The name of the script must, of course, be foo.fish.  Essentially, it's a function that calls its containing file as a script.

```
#!/usr/bin/fish

function foo
  chmod 740 (status --current-filename)
  fish -c (status --current-filename)" __exec_script $argv"
end

if test "$_" = "source"
  or test -z "$argv"
  or ! test "$argv[1]" = "__exec_script"
  foo $argv
  exit
end

function __parse_args --argument option
  if test -z $option
    return  # No option to parse, return early
  end

  switch $option
    case -h --help
      echo "Shows this help and exits"
      exit 0  # How can we exit 0 instead of return?
    case -\*
      echo "Error: '$option' not a valid option"
      exit 1  # How can we exit 1 instead of return?
  end
end

set argv $argv[2..-1] # Remove first argument, the __exec_script magic token
__parse_args $argv[1]
echo foo
```

The chmod line isn't necessary, of course, if you do it yourself when installing the script.

The resulting file can be called as a script:

```
~/.config/fish/functions/foo.fish      # Results in "foo"
~/.config/fish/functions/foo.fish -h   # Results in "Shows this help and exits"
~/.config/fish/functions/foo.fish -i   # Results in "Error: '-i' not a valid option"
```

as a function ...

```
foo              # Results in "foo"
foo -h           # Results in "Shows this help and exits"
foo -i           # Results in "Error: '-i' not a valid option"
```

or sourced ...

```
source ~/.config/fish/functions/foo.fish         # Results in "foo"
source ~/.config/fish/functions/foo.fish -h      # Results in "Shows this help and exits"
source ~/.config/fish/functions/foo.fish -i      # Results in "Error: '-i' not a valid option"
```

... all with the same results:

Answer (score 2):

In `__parse_args`, you could return `1` for `-h`, and then

```
function foo
    __parse_args $argv[1]
        or return $status
    echo foo
end
```

That provides a non-zero return status for `-h`, but that's probably not a big deal.